# Grouping in LINQ to XML with "any" or first" aggregation

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to group following XML using LINQ to XML or XPath by `param/Type`. With grouping I would like to get any (or first, doesn't matter) value of `id` tag.

```
<list>
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <param>
        <type>A</type>
    </param>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <param>
        <type>A</type>
    </param>
</item>
<item>
    <id>3</id>
    <param>
        <type>B</type>
    </param>
</item>
<item>
    <id>4</id>
    <param>
        <type>B</type>
    </param>
</item>
```

Desirable results is

```
A - 1
B - 3
```

I've tried

```
var content = from item in doc.Descendants("item").Descendants("param")
group item by new
{
       mType = (String)item.Element("type"),                                                
} into g
select new
{
    mType = g.Key.mType,                              
};
```

but I cannot figure out how to reference ID that is higher in hierarchy , or how to reference PARAM/TYPE when selecting ID.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `using System.Xml.Linq` ([XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

If my understanding is good, here is what I've done:

```
var xml = "<list><item><id>1</id><param><type>A</type></param></item><item><id>2</id><param><type>A</type></param></item><item><id>3</id><param><type>B</type></param></item><item><id>4</id><param><type>B</type></param></item></list>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var param in document.Root.Elements("item").GroupBy(i => i.Element("param").Element("type").Value))
{
    var firstId = param.First().Element("id").Value;
    Console.WriteLine ("The first of {0} = {1}", param.Key, firstId);
}
```

the output is :

```
The first of A = 1
The first of B = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was suggested by Cedric, you could accomplish the same thing in pure XPath:

```
var xml = "<list><item><id>1</id><param><type>A</type></param></item><item><id>2</id><param><type>A</type></param></item><item><id>3</id><param><type>B</type></param></item><item><id>4</id><param><type>B</type></param></item></list>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// start at the root, then grab the first item element which has a param/type element whose value is equal to 'B'
var answer = document.Root.XPathSelectElement("./item[./param/type='B'][1]").Element("id").Value;
```

In XPath, the square brackets function effectively like a where clause. My first set of square brackets qualify that I want an item that contains a matching param/type element. The second set of square brackets limit this down to the first match.